# 404 Not Found, но файл существует и открывается. CSM Битрикс

Tags: jquery, ajax, битрикс, http-status-code-404

Добрый день!

Не могу понять причину возникающей **404 ошибки**.
Делаю ajax подгрузку новостей на Битриксе. В общем, есть файл **inc_news.php**, в котором находится вызов компонента новостей. Этот inc_news.php подключается на главной странице через $APPLICATION->IncludeFile("/inc_news.php"); и выводит новости.

Далее по клику на ссылку идет обращение к **inc_news.php** с некоторыми параметрами за новой порцией новостей. В консоли вижу следующее:
**site.ru/inc_news.php?ajax=Y&PAGEN_1=2 404 (Not Found)**

Но необходимые данные приходят, в консоли видно, что нужные новости вместе с html кодом были возвращены ajax-ом.
Если открыть файл по прямой ссылке **site.ru/inc_news.php**, то все работает, новости выводятся. Но,  опять же, в консоли видно, что **статус страницы 404**.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема в `.htaccess`

Comment: @MAXOPKA .htaccess стандартный для битрикса. Попробовал менять параметры. Удалил файл полностью. Ошибка остается, видимо, дело в чем-то другом.